# zsh completion: different completion when stdin is a pipe

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

I have a program `foo`. It can be used in 2 different modes:

```
foo [-c] file1 [file2]
```

or

```
find . -print0 | foo [-0] [-c]
```

In first mode, the only optional argument is `-c`, and then there are one or more files.

In second mode, there are 2 optional arguments `-c` and `-0`, and no files.

How can I handle these 2 different modes in zsh completion?

Comment: Why would `-0` be invalid in the first mode? What if `file1` is a nul-delimited file (assuming this is what the option represents)? Would it have to be piped in, as in `cat file1 | foo -0` or `foo -0 <file1`.

Comment: Alias not help to you? Different names....